# Representation of $SL(3,\mathbb Z)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I read the paper "Real-analytic actions of lattices", it says that any representation of any finite-index subgroup of $SL(3,\mathbb Z)$ into $GL(2,\mathbb R)$ has finite image, so how to prove it? Another question is what is "the vector space of i-jets at x".

Comment: Seems to be this paper: http://www.google.com/search?as_q=farb+shalen+real+analytic+actions+lattices

Comment: You should avoid including 2 unrelated questions in the same post. (For the second one, the answer should be easy to find on the web.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest answer consists in invoking the Margulis superrigidity: such a representation should extend, in restriction to some finite index subgroup, to $SL_3(\mathbf{C})$, but it is easy to check that the latter has no nontrivial 2-dimensional representation.

There also exist older proofs based on a mixture of elementary and K-theoretic arguments akin to the congruence subgroup problem. (A first exercise is to check by hand that the image of every matrix $e_{ij}(n)$ in your finite index subgroup has finite order; also in case you subgroup is the entire $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Z})$, the full argument can be run by hand.)

Comment: Could you explain "such a representation should extend, in restriction to some finite index subgroup, to SL3(C)"? Thx.

Comment: @Antoine: Margulis superrigidity is well-documented on the web, have you looked?

Comment: Yes,I know this thm, but how to use it to prove?